Property 'element' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'
Giving error Property 'element' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'.Maybe Related to Schema. Model and codes are written in Typescirpt.
Map Model:
interface IMap extends Document {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  name: string;
  thumbnail?: string;
  mapElements: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId[];
}

const MapSchema: Schema<IMap> = new Schema({
  width: { type: Number, required: true },
  height: { type: Number, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  thumbnail: { type: String },
  mapElements: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'MapElements' }]
});

MapElement Model:

interface IMapElements extends Document {
  map: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  element: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  x?: number | null;
  y?: number | null;
}

const MapElementsSchema: Schema<IMapElements> = new Schema({
  map: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Map', required: true },
  element: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Element', required: true },
  x: { type: Number, default: null },
  y: { type: Number, default: null }
});

Error Code:
Here is Getting Property 'element' does not exist on type 'ObjectId' Error in e.element and e.x and e.y also showing similar error
 const map = await Map.findOne(
        { _id: parsedData.data.mapId },
        { width: 1, height: 1, mapElements: 1 }
      ).populate({
        path: 'mapElements',
        select: 'element x y',        
      });
      
      console.log(map);
      if (!map) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Map not found" });
        return;
      }
const spaceElementsData = map.mapElements.map((e) => ({
        space: space._id,
        element: e.element._id,
        x: e.x!,
        y: e.y!
      }));


Update Above issue is solve by populating like this:   .populate<{ mapElements: IMapElements[] }>('mapElements').exec();
